# Scala Spark - For loop in Data Frame and compare date

Tags: mysql, scala, apache-spark, rdd, bigdata

I have a Data Frame which has 3 columns like this:

```
---------------------------------------------
|  x(string)  |  date(date)  |  value(int)  |
---------------------------------------------
```

I want to SELECT all the the rows [i] that satisfy all 4 conditions:

1) row [i] and row [i - 1] have the same value in column 'x'

AND

2) 'date' at row [i] == 'date' at row [i - 1] + 1 (two consecutive days)

AND

3) 'value' at row [i] > 5

AND

4) 'value' at row [i - 1] <= 5

I think maybe I need a For loop, but don't know how exactly! Please help me!

Every help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be very easily done with Window functions, look at lag [function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$@lag(e:org.apache.spark.sql.Column,offset:Int):org.apache.spark.sql.Column):

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql._
import sqlContext.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions._

// test data
val list = Seq(
    ("x", "2016-12-13", 1),
    ("x", "2016-12-14", 7)
    );
val df = sc.parallelize(list).toDF("x", "date", "value");

// add lags - so read previous value from dataset
val withPrevs = df
    .withColumn ("prevX", lag('x, 1).over(Window.orderBy($"date")))
    .withColumn ("prevDate", lag('date, 1).over(Window.orderBy($"date")))
    .withColumn ("prevValue", lag('value, 1).over(Window.orderBy($"date")))

// filter values and select only needed fields
withPrevs
    .where('x === 'prevX)
    .where('value > lit(5))
    .where('prevValue < lit(5))
    .where('date === date_add('prevDate, 1))
    .select('x, 'date, 'value)
    .show()
```

**Note** that without order, i.e. by date, this cannot be done. Dataset has none meaningful order, you must specify order explicity

Comment: Thank you for your work! But have you considered condition 2)" 'date' at row [i] == 'date' at row [i - 1] + 1 (two consecutive days) "?

Comment: @zockking Sorry, I have missed that condition. I've updated question with this where

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DataFrame` created, then all you need to do is to call a **filter** function on DataFrame will all your conditions.

For example:

```
df1.filter($"Column1" === 2 || $"Column2" === 3)
```

You can pass as many  conditions as you want. It will return you a new DataFrame with `filtered data`.

Comment: I think it can be used to satisfy condition 3 and 4, but how can you filter condition 1 and 2??